# Aligning image to right of text in a list

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/JrXV8/4/

```
#nav ul img {
    display:inline-block;}
```

I'm trying to put a down arrow to the right of my top level "A" but have it so it is still clickable to down the menu down. What is the right way to do this?

1. Is it right it should be an image or instead put the image as a background to an empty span?
2. How do I get the image to sit to the right of the top level text instead of below it?

Comment: here is another way to solve the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JrXV8/10/

Comment: @NicoO It's a nice solution but the parent (A) is less wide that it's children. Is there a way to have the parent as wide as the children without a fixed width?

Comment: yes, it's basically the answer of @j08691 http://jsfiddle.net/JrXV8/12/

Comment: No sorry, I didn't word it right. I mean I don't want the menu to be 100% width, I want it to only be as wide as the widest child / parent item. Here you can see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JrXV8/13/ (it drops it down onto two lines)

Comment: Rule of the thumb: the less rules you need, the better your code will be. Here is the last help for this question: http://jsfiddle.net/JrXV8/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd remove the image from the HTML and add this CSS rule:

```css
#nav > li > a {
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Arrow-down-navmenu.png') 100% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JrXV8/9/)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you put the image inside the anchor tag? I think this results in your desired effect.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Vn6f/)

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        A <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Arrow-down-navmenu.png">
    </a>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav li a img{
 vertical-align:bottom;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
#nav li img {    
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Remember that position absolute adjust according to the next parent with position relative

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have a little typo!

Instead of `#nav ul img {`, it should read: `ul#nav img`!

Then, by adding: `cursor:pointer; position:absolute; top:15px; right:10px;`, you should be good!

http://jsfiddle.net/9j4xf/1/